# Is where/having going to be useful here?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks something like

```
SELECT to_number FROM sent_texts 
WHERE to_number NOT IN(SELECT mobile FROM action_6_members);
```

<strike>A WHERE is applied to the result set *after* the query is complete.</strike>
What would the effect be (improve/degrade) if the sub query contained

```
WHERE mobile = to_number
```

<strike>A HAVING is applied to the result set *during* the query.</strike>
What would the effect be (improve/degrade) if the sub query contained

```
HAVING mobile = to_number
```

What are the pros/cons of just using the original query?

---

**Update**
It seems my initial thoughts were wrong, thanks to [Bill Karwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929033/is-where-having-going-to-be-useful-here#3929076).

So Im going to update this with the explain of the original query.

This query is causing me my server to use 100% of the cpu.

Maybe someone can say why, and how to fix it?

```
id  select_type         table             type   possible_keys  key        key_len  ref  rows    Extra                     
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  action_6_members  index                 mobile     42            179218  Using where; Using index  
1   PRIMARY             sent_txts         index                 to_number  123           256066  Using where; Using index
```

This is the explain based off the join(after some more optimization)

```
id  select_type  table             type   possible_keys  key        key_len  ref  rows    Extra                                 
1   SIMPLE       sent_txts         index                 to_number  78            256066  Using index                           
1   SIMPLE       action_6_members  index                 mobile     27            179218  Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Comment: Run an `explain plan` on them both and compare the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the original query.  MySQL [optimizes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html) this case all right, especially if `mobile` is an indexed column.  It runs the non-correlated subquery once, and compares `to_number` to the set of `mobile` numbers reasonably efficiently.

I don't know where you got the ideas about `WHERE` conditions being applied after the query and `HAVING` conditions being applied during the query.  This is not accurate.

Think of it this way:

- `WHERE` conditions eliminate **rows** from the result set.  This is done during the query.
- `HAVING` conditions eliminate **groups** from the result set.  This is also done during the query, but after `GROUP BY` has collected rows into groups.

  You should not use `HAVING` if you aren't using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.
SELECT to_number FROM sent_texts 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT mobile FROM action_6_members where mobile = to_number);

I'm not sure if it will help. Try to compare the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for with your `WHERE mobile = to_number` is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT to_number
FROM sent_texts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM action_6_members
    WHERE mobile=sent_texts.to_number
);
```

In general correlated subqueries are undesirable. In this case though, MySQL should optimise both the correlated and the original subquery down to the same kind of `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`. You can check this with your data and indexes using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

In any case you are typically better off using joins rather than subqueries in MySQL, when you can. This null-join:

```
SELECT to_number
FROM sent_texts
LEFT JOIN action_6_members ON action_6_members.mobile=to_number
WHERE action_6_members.mobile IS NULL
```

Executed 33% faster than either subquery approach for me (may differ for your data; for small data the difference may not be measurable).

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` output in your update is a bit odd. It claims to be `Using index`, but the number of rows scanned in the subquery says otherwise and the `possible_keys` and `refs` columns are just missing. Do you have indexes on the `to_number` and `mobile` columns? You're going to need indexes to make this kind of query tolerable whether you use joins or subqueries.

Comment: Yeah, I have a btree index on both.

I just went And did some more optimization, So I will post a explain on your query

Comment: Maybe post the schema? Ensure that the columns have the same exact datatype (including collation)? If they're even slightly different it prevents the indexes being used togethers.